# How to play different animation on a view?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have an issue in Sencha Touch 2.
Working with routes is pretty cool but I have a question.

In my view **A** I have one button which redirects you to view "B".
Controller of A just calls: `redirectTo('routeB')`.

Controller of **B** calls method "active". This method sets B as active
item.

In view **B** I have a button, too which redirects you to View **C**.

Okay. The back button of view **C** just calls `redirectTo('routeB')`.

As you can see two view redirects to the view **B**. 
I want view **B** to slide right if I came from **C** and just pop if I
come from **A**.

Remember **A**  and **C** just do `redirectTo()`. Setting **B** as active
item is the job of the Controller of View **B** in method "active".

How can I play the right animation in `active` method?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [animateActiveItem](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-animateActiveItem)

use the following code it may help you.

Ext.getCmp('panelId').animateActiveItem(1, {type:'slide', direction:'left'});

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer but I think you misunderstood. My point is to know if I let view B animate with effectA or effectB. Because if I enter view B I want show another animation. And if I enter view B by backbutton of another view I want to show another animation. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [getShowAnimation()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-getShowAnimation) it may help you.